# Why some webpages are not opening in firefox?

Tags: firefox, yahoo

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 on my desktop. I have successfully connected my BSNL broadband and can access internet. I have upgraded to Firefox 8. The problem is some webpages are not opening in firefox. Pages like - yahoo.com, flickr.com, ubuntu forum pages etc and lots others are not opening but loading infinitely.

I have also installed google chrome. But same thing is happening there also. My modem is configured in bridge mode. I have disabled IPv6 in firefox. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Try to browse a page that doens't load, using the IP. For instance try Yahoo at  http://98.139.102.145

If the page loads, then most likely you have a DNS issue. Then you could try a different DNS provider like OpenDNS or Google DNS.

You could also try [DNS Flusher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dns-flusher/)